# C# Regex - Need to remove parentheses

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I'm looking for a C# regex for replacement to take this:

`HP06B66F (HP Officejet Pro 8600) (redirected 4)`

to

`HP06B66F (HP Officejet Pro 8600)`

I am using the regex below and it gets me to `HP06B66F (HP Officejet Pro 8600) ()`

`(redirected \\d*)`

I need to get it to remove that last `()` not just what is in between.

Thanks for the help

Comment: did you want the regex to replace if the input is `HP06B66F (HP Officejet Pro 8600) (foo bar)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex to `"\(redirected \d*\)"` to treat the () as normal characters.

(In C# depending on how you're doing this it might have to be `\\( and \\)` because you have to deal with the string's escape characters first)

Comment: This worked I had to use the escape characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need regex for that? You can do it like this:

```
string initialString = "HP06B66F (HP Officejet Pro 8600) (redirected 4)";
string wantedString = initialString.Remove(initialString.LastIndexOf("(")).TrimEnd();
```

Result:

[image: Result image]

You could also try with any of these, all giving the same result:

```
string wantedString = initialString.Replace(" (redirected 4)", "");
string wantedString = Regex.Replace(initialString, @"\(redirected \d*\)", "").TrimEnd();
```